# How to read userMetadata from a delta table stored in Unity Catalog?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am using DBR 13.3 LTS. How can I read metadata from a UC table?
Previously I read a "watermark" key from a dictionary stored as `userMetadata`, and doing it with the delta library.

The following code worked:

```
import delta
dt = delta.tables.DeltaTable.forPath(spark, absolute_path)
watermark_t1 = json.loads(dt.history().select(F.col("userMetadata")).first()[0])['watermark']
```

The path above is absolute, so now with Unity Catalog, I have to go to table details in Data Explorer and get the path on disc which is an ugly solution.

I would like to do the same but with UC syntax (..).